# "it is a [noun]" or "this is a [noun]"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, determiners

I ask my teacher is it right to say "**it** is a brain" or "**this** is a brain"? He answer me you can say both and I search google and found the same answer that both are correct. But I have some cockroaches in my brain that it should not be **this** and **it** at the same time.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Logically as a programmer you can use your awesome brain, the brain is a living organ which is listening your commands and performing through your blood.
You can only say a living organ with command **THIS** until **this** is alive.
You can't say or call a dead brain with command **THIS** but you call **it** with command **it**.

> Call Living Brain **This**.
>
> Call Dead Brain **it**.

Comment: Downvoted because iti[the answer] is absolutely wrong. **What is it?** "It" may refer to any inanimate thing, or any living or dead creature. It is less common  to ask "**What is this**?"

Comment: Ditto. This is clearly wrong and should not be accepted.

Answer (score 6):

"What is the organ shown in this picture?" "It is a brain."

"What organs do these pictures show?" "This is a brain, and this is a heart."

We use *it* to refer to something already identified, and *this* or *that* to identify something.